# Queue Publisher filtering in Tridion 8.5

Tags: publishing, web8.5, topology-manager, powershell

In the Tridion Management Console in 2013 we can configure a publisher server for publishing to stage and another for publishing to live, by adding the publishing target tcmid into the Publication Targets field.

So how do we do that in Tridion 8.5 with Topology?

[SDL 8.5 Documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-655433CE-6AB3-4A21-AE4C-A263A92C9FF9) for Queue settings

> "You can configure a host to only process messages for a specific
>   Publication Target"

Where do I get a publication target tcmid for the filter?

[image]

**Edit:**
Queried the database to get Publication Targets.

```
SELECT 'tcm:0-' +  CAST( [ID] as  varchar(10)) + '-65537' as 'tcmid' ,[TITLE]
FROM [Tridion_cm].[dbo].[PUBLICATION_TARGETS]
where IS_EMULATED = 1
```

> Is this really the recommended way to find the Publication Target data for configuring Publishers?

**Edit:**

[image]

### **PowerShell Solution**

```
#
# GetBPTPublishingTargets.ps1
#
<#
.Synopsis
Get BPT Publishing Targets
.DESCRIPTION
    Queue Publisher filtering in Tridion 8.5
    There is no GUI to show Business Process Type Publishing Target Type for Publication Filtering
    https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19363/queue-publisher-filtering-in-tridion-8-5/19451#19451

.EXAMPLE
Example of how to use this cmdlet
.INPUTS
None
.OUTPUTS
GridView 
.NOTES
Produced by Chris Mills Tridionation Ltd 
chris.mills@tridionation.com  07768805566
#>

$modulename = "SQLPS"
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name $modulename ) {
    #Write-Host "$modulename already installed"
    Import-Module -Name $modulename
}
else {
    $modulename = "SqlServer"
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name $modulename ) {
        Write-Host "$modulename already installed"
    }
    else {
        # Install the installer
        if (-not(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PowerShellGet)) { 
            Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force 
        }
        Install-Module -Name $modulename -Force
    }
    Import-Module -Name $modulename
}


if (-not $setupOptions) {
    Write-Error "Please initialse setupOptions"
    break
}

if (-not $credential) {
    $credential = Get-Credential  -Message "Remote Server Tridion Administrator SUP Account"
}

$tridion_cm = $setupOptions.CM_DB_NAME
$GetBPTPublishingTargetsTemplate = @"
    SELECT 'tcm:0-' +  CAST( [ID] as  varchar(10)) + '-65537' as 'tcmid' ,[TITLE] as 'Publication Target'
    FROM [$tridion_cm].[dbo].[PUBLICATION_TARGETS]
    where IS_EMULATED = 1
"@
$GetBPTPublishingTargets | Out-Null

$DatabaseComand = @{
    Query          = ""
    Database       = $setupOptions.CM_DB_NAME
    ServerInstance = $setupOptions.CM_DB_HOST
    UserName       = $setupOptions.SA_ACCOUNT_NAME
    Password       = $setupOptions.SA_PASSWORD
}

try { 
    $DatabaseComand.query = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($GetBPTPublishingTargetsTemplate)
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd @DatabaseComand
    $title = "SDL* Business Process Types Target Type ID - Tridionation Ltd 2018"
    $result | Out-GridView -Title $title
}
catch {
    Write-Output "SQL Query Error"
    Write-Output $error   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL* Case 00379116

Subject: Queue Publisher filtering in Tridion 8.5:

Mon 29/10/2018 12:47

> There is no current way available to find and filter by publication
> target other than the way you have found.
>
> There is an enhancement request is outstanding to address this issue for the GUI.
> You can also up-vote the request by visiting this community ideas link:
> https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/add-possibility-to-filter-publish-transactions-by-purpose-for-scaled-out-publishers
>
> You can also follow the progress via the product request on the gateway with reference: CRQ-5213

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find Publication Target info in PUBLICATION_TARGETS table from DB.
In Web 8.5 even though we enable Legacy Publishing we cannot see those targets, Looks like those are hidden as we will not be using in Web 8.5